# calling the service URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to call a credit card WSDL soap service in my ASP.net web forms. I tried to add the reference of the service in my application. I got the error "Page cannot be displayed. I asked the vendor and he told me that I am using older version  of .net and I should use below line of code  to fix the issue

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Where should I put the above line in my code and by putting the above, will I be able to call the service. Below is the screenshot of the error message when I am trying to call the service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to add a web reference on a project in visual studio.

1. **Using an Url**. In this case you can try typing the url on any browser and adding ?wsld at the end of the url, it should to show you the contract just there (like and xml). If it works then you can use THAT url (including the ?wsdl part) as the reference.
2. **From a local file.** In this case you can download the wsdl file from the browser (changing the extension to .wsdl when you download it) using the same way as I explained before but when the browser shows you the xml then you download it with the right click. Then in the web reference URL you can reference to the local path of the file.

Comment: I tried the URL with ?WSDl at the end and got Page not displayed error again. Do I need to use this ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12  anywhere.